# How to auto-boot my Windows 10 machine only on weekday mornings?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I haven't been able to find a way to do this.  I'm leaning towards it being impossible, but thought I'd ask here as a final resort.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte X299 UD4.  The UEFI supports auto boot, but has no options for what days, just a time.  So it's been booting up every morning which works fine, but I would really like it to not boot on weekends.  Is there any way to make this so?

Comment: would this help ? https://www.amazon.ca/Digital-FosPower-Programmable-Electrical-3-Prong/dp/B07958YD8R?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_1

Comment: I suppose I could set a physical timer on the AC outlets to only give power on weekdays.  But then when I DO want to use it on the weekends (I just don't want the machine on warming up my office from 4:30am) then I have to go mess with the timer to turn it on, or remove it, etc.  I would vastly prefer a "software" solution of some sort.  But thanks for the attempt.

Comment: You could suspend it (ACPI 4?) and send a WOL packet at the specified time.  Not exactly what you're looking for, understood.

Comment: Yeah, then I'd have to have another machine turn on first just to wake this one up.  Plus I disable WOL otherwise the machine wakes randomly after I put it to sleep from misc. network traffic.  But nice thought.

Comment: https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/four-ways-to-remotely-reboot-a-windows-machine/ - might get you one step further, also google sysinternals psshutdown.

Comment: Thanks for that, but unless I misread something, sysinternals is only for rebooting and shutting down, not for actually booting a machine from a shutdown state, on a schedule.  Did I miss something?